# Is user input list equivalent to a normal list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

def ifKilled(bullet, hp, target):
    shot=False
    length=len(hp)
    while bullet>0 and hp[target]!=0: 
        bullet-=1
        hp[random.randrange(length)] -= 1
    if hp[target]==0:
        shot=True
    return shot
input1 = input('Enter the hp of all possible target:')
input2 = int(input('Enter the target:'))
finput1 = [int(n) for n in input1.split(' ')]
print(finput1)
print("target is:"+str(input2))
c=0
t=0
while c<1000:
    #if ifKilled(3, [30,2],1):   
    if ifKilled(3, finput1, input2):
        t+=1
        #print(str(t))
    c+=1
print(t/1000)
```

The above code, ifKilled requires a list and a int as arguements, but when I input a list by hardcoding, it gives me a different answer than the one with user input list(both list are [30,2]). do I do anything wrong in getting the user list? 
what I do is type in 302 in the input, it should get a list identical to [30,2] list, right?

Comment: Print your lists and tell us what they look like.

Comment: what I do is type in 30<space>2 in the input, it should get a list identical to [30,2] list, right?

Comment: You should print out the value of the list or actually compare the two... That would tell you if the problem is actually the logic of the ifKilled function, which you didn't show

Comment: adding the code of `ifkilled` might help us understand better

Comment: @JohnZwinck my list is just [30, 2], and I type in 30<space>2 in the input area. and it does print out [30,2], but the calculation is different when I hardcoding this list into the arguement.

Comment: How does the output differ? Could you show us the actual `ifKilled` function? What is the expected output and what are you getting instead? Don't omit relevant information or we have no way to help.

Comment: the expected output should be around 0.5, the idea is if I have three"bullets" and two targets, one is 30 and another is 2, and I shoot randomly, what is the chance of killing the second one.

Comment: when I hardcode the list [30,2] into the function, it returns a right answer which is around 0.5, when I use input(which is still [30,2] ) it gives me an answer around 1. I tried many times so there is no coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that you mutate `hp` argument inside `ifKilled` function.

When you pass `finput1` list to `ifKilled`, it is reused in the iterations of the `while` loop.

When you pass `[30, 2]` to `ifKilled`, it is created anew for each iteration, hence any changes to it in `ifKilled` are not saved.